# GTK - Python Treeview Column Reorder Warnings

Tags: python, python-3.x, treeview, gtk, gtk3

I have a simple GTK GUI with a **treeview** on it. It gives the following errors when I drag columns to reorder. How this problem could be fixed?

**Warnings:**

> `Gtk-WARNING **: 15:43:03.151: Negative content width -8 (allocation 1, extents 5x4) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkButton)`
>
> `Gtk-WARNING **: 15:43:03.151: Negative content height -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkButton)`
>
> `Gtk-WARNING **: 15:43:05.886: Negative content width -8 (allocation 1, extents 5x4) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkButton)`

**Simplified Code:**

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file('test.glade')
window1 = builder.get_object('window1')
treeview1 = builder.get_object('treeview1')

class Signals:
    def on_window1_destroy(self, widget):
        Gtk.main_quit()

list_data = [["text1", "data1", "data2"], ["text2", "data1", "data2"], ["text3", "data1", "data3"]]

treestore1 = Gtk.TreeStore(str, str, str)
piter1 = treestore1.append(None, list_data[0])
piter2 = treestore1.append(piter1, list_data[1])
piter3 = treestore1.append(piter1, list_data[2])

treeview1.set_model(treestore1)

for i, column_title in enumerate(["col1", "col2", "col3"]):
    renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i)
    treeview1.append_column(column)
    column.set_sort_column_id(i)
    column.set_resizable(True)
    column.set_reorderable(True)

treeview1.expand_all()

builder.connect_signals(Signals())
window1.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Software versions: `GTK 3, Python 3.8.`

***Important:***

- Glade GUI file will be given if needed.
- I had similar warnings for a `listview` in my previous attempts.

Comment: It seems that at some point of the process your columns desappear. Try setting the sizing property to gtk.TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_GROW_ONLY or gtk.TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_AUTOSIZE

Comment: @Ulises Martínez Elías, I have tried commands ```column.set_sizing(0)``` (grow_only) and ```column.set_sizing(1)``` (autosize) respectively, but they did not prevented the warnings. Also resizing the columns to the minimum size gives similar warnings.

Comment: @demirod I did not get a notification, like you already guessed. I happened to stumble on this question. As far as the error, I see it a lot in my apps, with no problems. The other answers explain it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same problems with a GTK listview a long time ago. I could not fix the problem. But it may be a bug of the software. There are some examples on the web that contains similar problems ([link1](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/1275), [link2](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/2645)).

They have negative column warnings when treeview columns are resized to 0 or column header buttons are moved in order to reorder them. GTK versions are 3.22 and 3.24 for them. I do not know if it is fixed, I do not have the latest version installed.

Answer (score 0):

If setting the sizing property to `gtk.TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_GROW_ONLY` does not prevent the warnings and the warnings don't make the application crash, it is safe to let them there by now. It seems a GTK bug.

If you are interested in check the repo issues [GTK negative content issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/2645) but it does not promise much; they haven't been solved. So, though the warnings are annoying, they seem to be inoffensive